# Class that counts the number of objects created + random number generator Java

Tags: java

Alright, complete noob here trying to learn how to code. Sorry in advance.

My mission is to create a class "Ping" that contains a class varieble that keeps track of how many "Ping-objects" I create. These Ping-objects should have 4 attributes whose value is randomly generated when the object is created. These values should be INTEGERS between 0-255. When these objects are created these attributes should also be printed formated as follow:

172.15.256.1
192.165.0.0
10.100.68.215

The only code I have thus far is this and I´m pretty sure it´s completely useless lol. Any help is greatly appreciated!

````
package ping;

import java.util.Random;

public class Ping {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rnd = new Random();


        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int r1 = rnd.nextInt(255);
            int r2 = rnd.nextInt(255);
            int r3 = rnd.nextInt(255);
            int r4 = rnd.nextInt(255);



          System.out.println(r1 + "." + r2 + "." +r3 + "." + r4 );```
```OUTPUT 

141.143.64.132

20.121.58.51

40.54.128.90

226.161.89.26```
````

Comment: You should start at the beginning: 1. *My mission is to create a class "Ping"* <- You already did that, so move on to the next step 2. *that contains a class varieble* <- You did not add a single "class variable" to your created class. So creating it would be your next step

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to define the fields and constructor for the `Ping` class (consider adding getter methods if you need to retrieve the values). In order to find out how many pings you have created, you need to use a static field (a static field has the same value regardless of where it is accessed from and can be accessed using the class, as `Ping.number`, you don't necessarily need an instance of a `Ping` object). When you make a `new Ping()` object, the constructor is called, and all 4 fields are initialized randomly. Also, the `number` is incremented, so this is how you actually keep track of how many objected you created. Note that the `toString` method is used to convert a `Ping` object to a string, so it can be nicely printed to the console.

```
public class Ping {
    int r1;
    int r2;
    int r3;
    int r4;
    
    public static int number = 0;
    
    Ping () {
        number++;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        r1 = rnd.nextInt(255);
        r2 = rnd.nextInt(255);
        r3 = rnd.nextInt(255);
        r4 = rnd.nextInt(255);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return r1 + "." + r2 + "." + r3 + "." + r4;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ping ping1 = new Ping();
        Ping ping2 = new Ping();
        System.out.println("pings: " + Ping.number + "\np1: " + ping1 + "\np2: " + ping2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
pings: 2
p1: 177.127.106.216
p2: 164.221.52.251
```

Answer (score 1):

With the new `Java8` `Arrays` and `Stream` libraries you can get a more performant solution for your class with less lines of code.
Also You need to override the `toString()` method to be able to print your ping objects.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Ping {
    private static int count = 0;
    private int[] arr = new int[4]; 
   // Declare them as an array instead of separate variables.

    Ping () {
        ++count;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Arrays.setAll(arr, i -> rnd.nextInt(255)); // similar to for(int i = ...)
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    // The stream collects all ints into a '.' separated string.
    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining("."));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ping ping1 = new Ping();
        Ping ping2 = new Ping();
        System.out.println("Ping Count: " + Ping.getCount() + "\nPing1: " + ping1 + "\nPing2: " + ping2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Ping Count: 2
Ping1: 212.55.226.115
Ping2: 140.132.194.210
```